# Value set using Setter method in Runnable implimentation with bean scope prototype is not accessible in run method

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Dummy Code snippet of problem statement:
   Scheduler method

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 30000)
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public void scheduledTask() {

    TaskExecutor threadPool = ctx.getBean(TaskExecutor.class);
    long totalCount = someDao.someOperation("argument");
    Runner runner;
    for (int offset = 0; offset < totalCount; offset += 50) {
        runner = ctx.getBean(Runner.class);
        runner.setOffset(offset);
        threadPool.execute(runner);
    }
}
```

Runnable Implimentaion

```
@Component
@Scope(scopeName="prototype", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
@Transactional
public class Runner implements Runnable {

    private Integer offset;
    private Integer limit;

    private ISomeDao someDao;

    public Runner(ISomeDao someDao) {
        this.someDao = someDao;
    }

    public void setOffset(int offset) {
        this.offset = offset;
        this.limit = this.offset + 50;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        List<Operation> operations = someDao.fetchData(offset, limit,  someCriteria);
        ///
        /// other business logic

    }

}
```

Problem that i am facing:

In scheduledTask, program set the value of offset correctly(check in debug mode),
but it is not accessible in run method of the Runner class, offset it always null.
When i remove the spring annotation from Runner class and instantiate it mannuly in 
scheduledTask then i can access the offset value, but it will throw exception as 
there is no transaction manager available which is expected.

I also tried to inject the EntityManger in the

```
runner = ctx.getBean(Runner.class, ctx.getBean(EntityManager.class);
```

in the scheduledTask
when i remove the Spring  annotation, but the problem remain the same as Thread is not managed by Spring

I have spent hour finding the solution.

Comment: Did you try to use the default spring scope singleton? Does it work? If it work it means that in order to execute the job spring creates a new runner object where offset is not set

Comment: Agree with @AngeloImmediata. You need to try different scope to your bean. prototype will create different objects for different requests. So it might be the problem.

Comment: @AngeloImmediata It works in default scope, but my requirement is prototype. Also I added debug point in Runner constructor to check how many time object is created and for every loop spring is creating 2 instance and when i comment out the **runner.setOffset(offset)** line in scheduledTask() , object is created only once. Is it expected behaviour in spring. With my understanding, in prototype scope new object is created by spring every time Bean is referenced, which in my case is **runner = ctx.getBean(Runner.class);** Am i wrong ?

Comment: It seems really strange to me that just executging `runner.setOffset(offset)` the object is created twice. With prototype scope creates a new instance every time the object is injected in other beans or the `getBean` method is used (https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-scopes-prototype). I guess there are 2 instances not for the setOffset but because the runner is injected in some way